# SAS: filter a dataset using another datasets columns

Tags: sas

Using SAS: I have two datasets, data1 and data2. Data1 has policy ID and transaction date for cars. Data2 also has policy ID and trasnaction date for trailers. I want to filter data2 to only have policy IDs that are in data1 and then filter those polcies to only be included if trasnaction date in data1 is less than trasnaction date in data2.

[Image of fake datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8zbs.png)

the want table is what I'm aiming for and the datasets have over 100,000 transactions.

I tried to merge the datasets using a key but my code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only posted pictures we cannot provide tested code.

Let's assume that DATA1 has ID and DATE1 and DATA2 has ID and DATE2.  Also let's assume that ID uniquely identifies the observations in both datasets. And that both are already sorted by ID.

So just merge and compare the two dates and only keep those were DATE1 is not missing and also less than DATE2.

```
data want;
  merge data1 data2;
  by id;
  if .Z < date1 < date2 ;
run;
```